# Gradle Git Push over SSH

Tags: git, gradle, ssh, git-push, multi-project

I am trying to achieve **git clone, git commit, git push** operations for multiple projects using this git repo code "[Multiproject Git - Gradle Script](https://github.com/RonakKosamia/multiproject-git-gradle) "  .

This code works perfectly with Git Clone operation, But somehow it doesn't work when I do commit or push. it accepts git commit and push commands via gradle without any error(shows success message) but when I clone repo again to verify contents , it comes empty.

I tried using direct commands on my git url, it works fine. 
but with this script I am not able to achieve same.

I am sure that git clone is working fine, the way it should work. but git commit or git push is not sending any files from local cloned repo to remote repo.

If any one can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you run the script? What errors do you get?

Comment: No error at all.check output image

Comment: You should copy and paste the output here rather than a screenshot. For one thing, I see "BUILD FAILED" but the error for this is hidden. Or is that unrelated? Which is then another reason to just paste the text directly. It is much easier to show only the related information that way.

Comment: "BUILD FAILED" is unrelated. first I ran clone task, then gitCommmit, and then gitPush . all were successful. Think-2:multiproject-git-gradle rk$ gradle maybeClone
:AnkAndroid_maybeClone
:maybeClone

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.088 secs
Think-2:multiproject-git-gradle rk$ gradle gitCommit
...
:AnkAndroid_gitCommit
AnkAndroid : committing changes
:gitCommit

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.961 secs
Think-2:multiproject-git-gradle rk$ gradle gitPush
...
AnkAndroid : pushing master to origin
:gitPush

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: I am confused. If the script runs successfully, then what is the problem?

Comment: That's the question. script runs successfully but it is  doesn't works the way it should. it doesn't upload any file to git server with git push operation.